# Insert into table (select from another table) and some parameters

Tags: mysql

I want to insert into one table selecting values from another table and some with paramters.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `insertuser`(
    IN `param1` VARCHAR(50)

)
BEGIN

insert into users(firstname,lastname,email) 
select name,nickname,@param1 from members
where id=3;
END
```

I fill param1 but the query insert null to email
what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` symbol is used to define [Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) (accessible to the Session everywhere). You don't need to use `@` here, as you are using the input parameter value from the Stored procedure.

Try the following instead:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `insertuser`(IN `param1` VARCHAR(50))
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname,email) 
    SELECT name,nickname,param1 -- remove @ from @param1 here
    FROM members
    WHERE id=3;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```